# Xpath Contains OR definition clarification

Tags: xpath

While sifting through websites with Scrapy, I had a general question regarding the usage of Xpath's contain and or to be able to create more concise statements.

For example, when looking for the link 'contacts' in both Spanish and English websites I've been using the following Xpath query:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Contact') or contains(text(), 'Contact Us') or contains(text(), 'Contactar') or contains(text(),'Contacto') or contains(text(), 'Contáctenos')]
```

The issue I am facing is that the query above might have some ambiguities. For example, if a website had a 'Contacto' and a 'Contactenos' link, it isn't very clear to me which one would be returned. I have tried changing the order, but there seems to be no difference regarding which one will be returned like most `or` statements I am used to working with. Does anyone know how the 'or' keyword runs?

Comment: It depends on the method you used. If you use `.findAll` then you will get both `'Contacto' and a 'Contactenos' links`. Where as `.find` will get the first matching node meaning that which ever first appear on the page source. It doesn't matter, even the first matching  occurrence is mentioned at the last place in the xpath.

Comment: Is it possible to change the order so that the first matching node is not the one that is returned?

Comment: No.  why can't to restrict the xpath to specific div or location rather checking in the entire page. `//div[@property='only_in_this_div']//*[your or condition]` by that way you don't have to worry about the other links displayed in page with matching xpath.

Comment: The context of the project is to check for these conditions throughout multiple web pages that all use different formatting. By limiting it to a specific scenario, it limits the applicability of the query to only a specific type of page.